# HTML5 geolocation more accurate on Windows than Linux (Firefox, Chrome, [Chromium])

Tags: linux, windows, html, geolocation

I've been playing with HTML5 geolocation and noticed that I get consistently better results on my Windows system than on my Linux system.

I dual boot, so hardware is identical. Wifi is on in both scenarios, and there's no GPS adapter built in.

By more accurate I mean that on Windows the location shown is usually within 50-100m of my actual location, while on Linux the location is off by ~6km (and it never varies, it always shows the exact same location, basically the city center).

Tested on Chrome and Firefox on Windows, and Chrome, Chromium and Firefox on Linux.

Update: Just tested on Safari/Mac OSX. Same precision as in Windows. So Linux is the only system with bad results :(

Can anybody reproduce this? Do Firefox and Chrome on Linux not make use of the WiFi as an additional source of location information? What else am I missing here?

Thanks for your valuable input!

Answer (score 2):

Acording to this article: [HTML5 geolocation accuracy](http://www.andygup.net/?p=600)

> Not all Geolocation services are the same, and they certainly don’t all use the same algorithms and exact same databases. Because of this the results typically vary across browsers that use different Geolocation services.

It also explains that Firefox on Windows uses Google Location Services. Firefox on Linux uses GPSD, GPS daemon is a service for geolocation on Linux.

That may be the reason for the difference in accuracy.

Comment: Thanks Luciano! Guess this answers most of my questions, except for the difference between Chrome on Windows and Linux (which, according to that link, both use Google location services). I'm proably gonna do some more testing soon, including tests with an external GPS device and gpsd on Linux.

Comment: You are welcome, it is a very interesting question. I'm also working on geolocation so if you find out anything else please tell us.